# How do I get past NDK build failure in cpu-features.c?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm attempting to build NDK compatible code (that works and has been tested), but I'm getting the following error during the build process:

```
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : cpufeatures <= cpu-features.c
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c: In function 'get_elf_hwcap_from_proc_self_auxv':
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c:534:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'typeof' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     int fd = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(open(filepath, O_RDONLY));
     ^
In file included from /Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/fcntl.h:34:0,
                 from /Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c:75:
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/unistd.h:207:18: error: expected ';' before '_rc'
     typeof (exp) _rc;                      \
                  ^
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c:534:14: note: in expansion of macro 'TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY'
     int fd = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(open(filepath, O_RDONLY));
              ^
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/unistd.h:209:9: error: '_rc' undeclared (first use in this function)
         _rc = (exp);                       \
         ^
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c:534:14: note: in expansion of macro 'TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY'
     int fd = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(open(filepath, O_RDONLY));
              ^
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/unistd.h:209:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
         _rc = (exp);                       \
         ^
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c:534:14: note: in expansion of macro 'TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY'
     int fd = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(open(filepath, O_RDONLY));
              ^
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/unistd.h:207:18: error: expected ';' before '_rc'
     typeof (exp) _rc;                      \
                  ^
/Users/sean/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c:544:19: note: in expansion of macro 'TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY'
         int ret = TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY(read(fd, (char*)&entry, sizeof entry));
                   ^
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cpufeatures/cpu-features.o] Error 1
```

I've tried setting AP_ABI to different architectures, but with more or less the same result. My local dev environment is OSX and I'm running this directly using `ndk-clean & ndk-build`

Anyone else figure this out?

Comment: Linking to an image on a image sharing site is a bad idea.  Cut and paste the text into your Question.

Comment: Which toolchain are you building with? If you're using Clang, try specifying a GNU mode such as `-std=gnu99` (or `-std=gnu++11` if you're compiling with the C++ compiler)

Comment: Thanks @Michael - looks like switching the CFLAGS to `-std=gnu99` from `-std=c99` did the trick.